# Rails devise customize views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I know this question has been ask before some times, but no solution could help me.
I have two devise models:client and admin. For the client I want a different sign up form than the admin has. I looked at the devise git hub page and did this:

1)rails generate devise:views <-- When I change something here it works

2)rails generate devise:views client <-- When I change something here it does not work

And yes I did this:

3)config.scoped_views = true

I even tried to put the client folder inside the devise folder, did not help :(

So is there anything I have missed ? Or any trick I might try?

Comment: client folder must be here  app/views/
finally it looks like app/views/clients/sessions/new .
Try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should type :

> rails generate devise:views clients

(With a 's' at the end)